# Across which terminals is EMF induced in this circuit?

Tags: voltage, electromagnetic, induction

[image]

If I were to place a circuit such as this in a changing magnetic field, across which terminals would an EMF be induced? If the field were into the plane

My intuition suggests across all wires lying parallel to the y-axis, but I'm unable to come up with any scientific reason for it.

Comment: What is the direction of the magnetic field?

Comment: into the plane.

Comment: So how does your magnetic field chabge?

Comment: @fhhh all wires will have an induced voltage in that case.

Comment: so all 7 segments will have the same induced voltage simultaneously?

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat, jus changing with  time, nothing else.'

Answer (score 0):

The question is not complete:

1. You are asking

> Across which terminals is EMF induced?

but, your drawn loop has no "***terminals***". I will then assume you mean "***in which wires?***"

2. The induced voltage will depend on the spatial distribution of the magnetic field, while it is changing with time. You have ***NOT*** mentioned anything about it. So, I will assume you mean spatially uniform magnetic field.

Under these assumptions, an induced current will flow in all wires except for the middle vertical one. The induced EMF exists in all wires, and that middle wire has two opposite EMF's  cancelling each other with no current flow.